# Reading certain lines from a text file and assigning to separate variables

Tags: java, file-io, variable-assignment

I want to take a text file which contains strings and integers and individually take certain integers on each line and assign that specific integer to a variable to be later accessed by other classes. Here is what i have so far, I'm almost certain it will not work:

```
 public void openInputFile()
    {

     String fileName = "concerts.txt";
     Scanner inputStream = null;


    try{
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("error");
        System.exit(0);

    }
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        int capacityM =0 ;
        int ticketPriceM = 0;
        int capacityO = 0;
        int ticketPriceO = 0;
        int capacityP = 0;
        int ticketPriceP = 0;


        if (inputStream.equals("Maroon 5")){
            capacityM = inputStream.nextInt(); //I want to read line #2 of the txt file assign it here
            ticketPriceM = inputStream.nextInt();//Line 3 of txt file needs to be assigned here
        }
            else if(inputStream.equals("One Direction")){
                capacityO = inputStream.nextInt(); //
                ticketPriceO = inputStream.nextInt();
            }
                else {
                    capacityP = inputStream.nextInt();
                    ticketPriceP = inputStream.nextInt();

                }
        System.out.println(capacityM + ticketPriceM + capacityO + 
                ticketPriceO + capacityP + ticketPriceP);
        }

    inputStream.close();

    }
}
```

Here is What the text file looks like that is being read from. I'm not sure if i should use arrays.

```
Maroon 5
15     //number of tickets available
40     //ticket price
One Direction
10
50
Pearl Jam
20
30
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted.. remember to explain why, otherwise you waste a downvote and the poster will not learn what he did wrong and might do the same mistake in a future post.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine` method to read the line from file. Than use `equals` method to compare `String` at `else-if`

```
  String line=inputStream.nextLine();//Call nextLine only once
                                     //than use the line to compare 
                                     //different condition
   if (line.equals("Maroon 5")){
     ....
   }else if(line.equals("One Direction")){
   .....
   }
```

Comment: @user3029836,  Correct.

Comment: how can i quickly test this? i have a test class, how do i call upon it to see if this works? @Masud